# Componente para substituir Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Estou tendo muitos problemas com Gridview em Asp.Net que estão me tirando do sério, principalmente a parte de paginação e exportação dos dados.

Existe algum outro componente free no mercado, que substitui o gridview e que seja mais completo?

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo do grau de substituição, o [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/) pode ser uma opção. O problema é que sua abordagem mudaria para HTML puro, o que poderia dar algum trabalho.